# How can I completely disable user interface in Jasper Reports for specific user/role?

Tags: access-control, jasperserver

We have developed a few reports in Jasper v 6.3.0. we call these reports from a web interface we have developed. We would like to completely disable the Jasper user interface for the user/role that we have assigned these reports to.

Right now if the user strips the right hand side of the url they get a screen that allows them to see the repository, look at the reports, etc. Although as a non admin user they cannot change things we would like to disable this screen completely.

An alternative would be to disable this screen from access other than from the local server, or the local network.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Edit - clarification:

Basically we developed the report using ireport. and then we deploy it to JasperReportServer. We then "link" to the report on JasperReportServer from our web application. If you strip the url of everything after "/jasperserver" it displays a UI panel. I want to disable that panel.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Report generates a jasper design and this design is written a file/stream etc. I think this issue can be done in a higher level not in Jasper. When user onmouseover "link", you can control the user via ajax and if is enabled you can show the panel.

Comment: I am not sure how this applies to my question. What I need is a way to disable the "https://www.mydomain/jaspersoft" default UI page.